# Get Azure Blob path from MapReduce

Tags: azure, mapreduce, azure-hdinsight, azure-blob-storage

In Hadoop, we can get map input file path as;

```
Path pt = new Path(((FileSplit) context.getInputSplit()).getPath().toString());
```

But I cannot find any documentation how to achieve this from Azure Blob Storage account. Is there a way to get Azure Blob path from mapreduce program?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the input file path for the current process of mapper or reducer, your code is the only way to get the path via `MapContext`/`ReduceContext`.

If not, to get the file list of the container defined in the `core-site.xml` file, try the code below.

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(configuration);
Path home = hdfs.getHomeDirectory();
FileStatus[] files = hdfs.listStatus(home);
```

Hope it helps.